# Fatal error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Client::request() with Guzzle 6

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-5

I'm using Guzzle 6 with Laravel 5.2.

I'm trying to access a simple internal API:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => getenv('URL_BASE').'api/v1/']);
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'tournaments');
```

And I get this message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Client::request()
```

When I see the [docs](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/docs/quickstart.rst), it says:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://foo.com/api/']);
```

But PHPStorm cannot resolve GuzzleHttp

What should I do to make it work???

Comment: Thats the docs for Guzze 6 (i guess?), you need the docs for 5 https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/5.3/docs/quickstart.rst

Comment: I was able to install Guzzle 6, but problem remains

Comment: Are you able to see the class `Client` in the PHPStorm? Maybe `composer update` or `composer install` is needed?

Comment: if I delete GuzzleHttp\, autocompletition gives me 2 choices: use GuzzleHttp\Client and use Guzzle\Http\Client; but none of them work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also using guzzle, and its working for me, Try like this

```
use GuzzleHttp;
use GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

And to get response try this

```
$response = $client->request('GET', 'tournaments',['query' => ['base_uri' => getenv('URL_BASE').'api/v1/']]);
```

OR try this if not work

```
$response = $client->request('GET', getenv('URL_BASE').'api/v1/tournaments');
```

Comment: This is indeed working and it is actually based on the version of Guzzle you are using.

Comment: Be sure to "include" or "require" the vendor/autoload.php file.