# Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri::composeComponents()

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, guzzle

I can't seem to get a simple file upload to work on Laravel 5.4. I have my file system configured correctly with the proper environment variables for S3. When I process files to upload using this code:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
foreach ($request->allFiles() as $file) {
    $disk->putFileAs('file-requests', $file, $file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

I get this error:

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri::composeComponents()
in UriResolver.php (line 102)
at UriResolver::resolve(object(Uri), object(Uri))
in RestSerializer.php (line 206)
at RestSerializer->buildEndpoint(object(Operation), array('Bucket' => 'myBucket', 'Key' => 'file-requests/test_2MB.dump', 'Body' => object(Stream), 'ACL' => 'private', 'ContentType' => 'text/plain', 'ContentLength' => 2097152, '@http' => array()), array('body' => object(Stream), 'headers' => array('x-amz-acl' => 'private', 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain', 'Content-Length' => 2097152)))
in RestSerializer.php (line 48)
at RestSerializer->__invoke(object(Command))
in Middleware.php (line 97)
at Middleware::Aws\{closure}(object(Command), null)
in Middleware.php (line 81)
at Middleware::Aws\{closure}(object(Command), null)
in S3Client.php (line 421)
at S3Client::Aws\S3\{closure}(object(Command), null)
in S3Client.php (line 444)
at S3Client::Aws\S3\{closure}(object(Command), null)
in S3Client.php (line 378)
at S3Client::Aws\S3\{closure}(object(Command), null)
in S3Client.php (line 397)
at S3Client::Aws\S3\{closure}(object(Command), null)
in Middleware.php (line 55)
at Middleware::Aws\{closure}(object(Command), null)
in SSECMiddleware.php (line 59)
at SSECMiddleware->__invoke(object(Command), null)
in IdempotencyTokenMiddleware.php (line 77)
at IdempotencyTokenMiddleware->__invoke(object(Command))
in AwsClientTrait.php (line 65)
at AwsClient->executeAsync(object(Command))
in ObjectUploader.php (line 90)
at ObjectUploader->promise()
in S3ClientTrait.php (line 44)
at S3Client->uploadAsync('myBucket', 'file-requests/test_2MB.dump', resource, 'private', array('params' => array('ContentType' => 'text/plain', 'ContentLength' => 2097152)))
in S3ClientTrait.php (line 29)
at S3Client->upload('myBucket', 'file-requests/test_2MB.dump', resource, 'private', array('params' => array('ContentType' => 'text/plain', 'ContentLength' => 2097152)))
in AwsS3Adapter.php (line 582)
at AwsS3Adapter->upload('file-requests/test_2MB.dump', resource, object(Config))
in AwsS3Adapter.php (line 367)
at AwsS3Adapter->writeStream('file-requests/test_2MB.dump', resource, object(Config))
in Filesystem.php (line 122)
at Filesystem->putStream('file-requests/test_2MB.dump', resource, object(Config))
in FilesystemAdapter.php (line 118)
at FilesystemAdapter->put('file-requests/test_2MB.dump', resource, array())
in FilesystemAdapter.php (line 152)
at FilesystemAdapter->putFileAs('file-requests/test_2MB.dump', object(UploadedFile), 'test_2MB.dump')
in FileRequestsController.php (line 373)
at FileRequestsController->upload(object(Request), object(FileRequest))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(FileRequestsController), 'upload'), array(object(Request), 'file_request' => object(FileRequest)))
in Controller.php (line 55)
at Controller->callAction('upload', array(object(Request), 'file_request' => object(FileRequest)))
in ControllerDispatcher.php (line 44)
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(FileRequestsController), 'upload')
in Route.php (line 203)
at Route->runController()
in Route.php (line 160)
at Route->run()
in Router.php (line 574)
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in BaseController.php (line 20)
at BaseController->App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 131)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in LoginUsingOldPlm.php (line 39)
at LoginUsingOldPlm->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in SubstituteBindings.php (line 41)
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Authenticate.php (line 43)
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 65)
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ShareErrorsFromSession.php (line 49)
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in StartSession.php (line 64)
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php (line 37)
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in EncryptCookies.php (line 59)
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Router.php (line 576)
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))
in Router.php (line 535)
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 513)
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 174)
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php (line 149)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php (line 52)
```

BUT the method IS defined. Maybe I am missing something but I can't see it. Any help is appreciated. Adding this at line 102 in the UriResolver.php:

```
$_uri = new Uri();
var_dump(method_exists($_uri, 'composeComponents'));
exit;
```

On my fresh Laravel install returns:

```
/home/vagrant/Code/test-aws/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/UriResolver.php:103:boolean true
```

On my large project it says:

```
/home/vagrant/Code/plm/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/UriResolver.php:103:boolean false
```

Even though it does exist. I believe the real question is what would make static methods on a class not exist or be uncallable. Moving the method into a variable I was able to complete my file upload to AWS but this is all kinds of wrong:

```
$composeComponents = function ($scheme, $authority, $path, $query, $fragment) {
    $uri = '';

    // weak type checks to also accept null until we can add scalar type hints
    if ($scheme != '') {
        $uri .= $scheme . ':';
    }

    if ($authority != ''|| $scheme === 'file') {
        $uri .= '//' . $authority;
    }

    $uri .= $path;

    if ($query != '') {
        $uri .= '?' . $query;
    }

    if ($fragment != '') {
        $uri .= '#' . $fragment;
    }

    return $uri;
};

//$_uri = new Uri();
//var_dump($_uri);
//var_dump(method_exists($_uri, 'composeComponents'));
//exit;

//return new Uri(Uri::composeComponents(
return new Uri($composeComponents(
    $base->getScheme(),
    $targetAuthority,
    $targetPath,
    $targetQuery,
    $rel->getFragment()
));
```

Comment: what version of laravel is this?

Comment: It uses Laravel 5.4.29

Comment: maybe this link would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236073/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-guzzlehttp-clientrequest-with-guzzle-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an autoloading issue.

I have a older website within Laravel that has its own autoloading. This occurred because a middleware always included a file from the older website which caused irregular behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your `vendor/` directory and reinstall all Composer dependencies.

It should be fine if you are using `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.2"`.

Comment: Laravel uses http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/adapter/aws-s3-v3/ which in turn uses AWS PHP SDK and within its composer file it says: "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^5.3.1|^6.2.1",

Comment: It means the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is relevant, and you use **Laravel**, then nothing needs to be removed and reinstalled.
Trying:

```
$response->transferStats->getHandlerStats()['url'];
```

If the error, then parse url:

https://doc.hotexamples.com/class/guzzlehttp.psr7/Uri#method-getPath

```
    $parse = $response->transferStats->getRequest()->getUri();
    $res = [
        'scheme' => $parse->getScheme().'://',
        'host' => $parse->getHost(),
        'path' => $parse->getPath()
    ];
    return implode('', $res);
```

$response - This is what you get in response from the server, there something in the form of ***json*** can come, looking at whose server you knock.

---

The second option works for me. I hope I helped someone.