# Gmail API cannot view threads

Tags: php, api, gmail-api, guzzle

I've been trying to list threads/view a specific thread in PHP and I keep getting the same error.

I have tried multiple examples ([all are from Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get)) but it says `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request::getMessages()`.

I'm not exactly sure why this is, all I had installed was the Google API package which I assume included guzzle but just to be safe I also installed guzzle and updated it to the latest version.

I don't know what I can do to fix this. My only guess is that maybe Google's package is using an outdated which is specified somewhere that doesn't support that method, but that wouldn't really make sense.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Client::request() with Guzzle 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236073/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-guzzlehttp-clientrequest-with-guzzle-6)

Comment: That thread's answer didn't work for me

Comment: Same issue. Did you solve this?

Comment: I updated the whole package, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this caused the issue:

```
$client->setDefer(true);
```

After removing it began to work.